# how to get an image with specific id from Facebook graph api iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app i am trying to fetch an specific image from a Facebook page photos/albums. I can get all the images just fine in an NSArray but how should i query the specific images which i want.

This is my url:@"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/albumid/photos" and this gives me an Array of images with their source url but their is no image id that i can use to get the image i want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this, [http://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=albums.fields(photos.fields(id,source,name,picture))](http://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=albums.fields%28photos.fields%28id,source,name,picture%29%29)

From this link you can get `id`, source and picture of an individual photo.

Comment: But then how would i get the image from the id. Lets say the person i want to get the image from his ABC, then what should be the request like? Would it be: http://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/ABC/photos/photoid

Comment: Do you mean to have a photo only when a photo id is passed? And, What is "ABC", Is it an album in your perception?

Comment: Yes i want to get the photo by photo id and ABC is userid

Comment: If you are having `photoid` then you can directly append it to graph API url and can get the `photo`, i.e, https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/photoid , and there is no need to use the user-id.

Answer (score 0):

You first get url from it then load url into `UIImageView`.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/?fields=picture",fbId] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NLog(@"JSON %@",responseObject);
        NSDictionary *pic = [responseObject objectForKey:@"picture"];
        NSDictionary *data = [pic objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSString *url = [data objectForKey:@"url"];

        [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {    
        NLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: But how i am going to know the id of the image for which i want to capture the url.

Comment: id in here is facebook ID.

Comment: That's the tricky part. Where would i get this id for a specific image from. Can you please give me url that i can test in browser/graph api explorer to clarify. I think the request above you are showing is only going to give me profile image

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using latest SDK

self.arrayMedia = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/albums" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id"} tokenString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FACEBOOK_ACCESSTOKEN"] version:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"]

 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"result albums:%@",result);
     NSLog(@"Error %@",error.description);

     for (NSDictionary *dict in result[@"data"]) {

         [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos", dict[@"id"]] parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,url,picture"} tokenString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FACEBOOK_ACCESSTOKEN"] version:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"]

          startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

              for (NSDictionary *dict in  result[@"data"])
              {
                  [self.aryMedia addObject:dict];
              }

          }];
     }
 }];
```