# Facebook Graph Api call not working for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For an iOS app, using facebook sdk i need to fetch photos from user's album but i need to fetch them in a single request so that i could get info about albums and containing photos at the same time, for that i tried

```
/me/albums?fields=count,name,photos.limit(10){images}
```

that api call is working fine in Graph api explorer but not on iOS platform. I only need **images** field of photos that is why using
above api call

If i run this api it runs fine

```
/me/albums?fields=count,name,photos.limit(10)
```

only **{images}** part is causing the problem, the error message which i get is of unsupported url, have acquired the permissions for **user_photos**

**Code :**

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/albums?fields=count,name,photos.limit(10){images}" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        if(!error) {
            NSLog(@"result %@",result);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error description : %@",error.description);
        }
    }];

    [connection start];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was making the final url call by adding/removing fields from graph api explorer side pane, the request call it was generating was

```
/me/albums?fields=count,name,photos.limit(10){images}
```

not working on iOS platform, but if i use this syntax instead

```
/me/albums?fields=count,name,photos.limit(10).fields(images)
```

to address fields of **photos** then it works fine, got the inspiration from answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501876/how-to-get-an-image-with-specific-id-from-facebook-graph-api-ios?rq=1)

Comment: I have been looking everywhere for this, thank you so much

Comment: You deserve a cookie!! I spent HOURS looking for it!