# com.facebook.sdk error 5 in phonegap ios

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble with the facebook api for phonegap on IOS. The login works fine, but when it gets to the permissions, the code below throws an error `The operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)` I replaced this part of the code `"me/albums?fields=id,photos{images,album}"` with this `"/me"`, and it does not  throw an error, but what I had was needed...

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/albums?fields=id,photos{images,album}", ["user_photos"],
    function (success) {
        // Success
    },
    function (failure) {
        alert(failure);
    }
);
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have the app id in the info.plist file, and the appended fb + app_id. This code works for the Android, it is only giving me problems in IOS

Edit:
I can reduce `"me/albums?fields=id,photos{images,album}"`
down to `"me/albums?fields=id,photos"` to remove the error. but I need the {images, album}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Phonegap, I had to go under Plugins -> FacebookConnectPlugin.m -> Under

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: ... NSError *error) {
    // Add this line below
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
}];
```

This fixed it temporarily, I still get the error occasionally because of Safari.

Turns out that IOS does not support the brackets. Instead I had to change the code from

```
//Before
"me/albums?fields=id,photos{images,album}"
//After
"me/albums?fields=id,photos.fields(images,album)"`
```

Thank @Zarar [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634766/facebook-graph-api-call-not-working-for-ios)